# Asking a colleague for his submitted paper

Tags: preprint

A colleague just told me about a paper he submitted to a conference, I'd love to have a look at his work out of curiosity.

How can I ask without him thinking I'm off to steal his ideas or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If he is a colleague, he is unlikely to think that. Just express your interest and ask for an early look. If something in it seems interesting to you contact him again and see if you have the possibility of collaboration on an extension or similar work.

It is how collaborative relationships get formed. Just do it.

Answer (score 3):

Just ask him or her.  I’m not sure how you can steal the ideas of someone who will make a public presentation on these ideas. Moreover, your colleague presumably has proof that has submitted this so there can no issue as to priority.

Answer (score 1):

I would have tried to discuss the work that he has done. This could be a very informal discussion over a coffee or a walk. Then, I would have asked if he could share the manuscript with me. If you both are going good with each other in professional sphere, it's not a difficult demand to fulfill.